# Cython - Wrapping pointer to structure from C to python

Tags: cython

I have a C function which take pointer to struct and i want to use it in python by C-Extensions by Cython way but when i want to pass pointer to struct from python give me an error: "Cannot convert Python object to 'Foo *'"
In the below example i make object to call the C function but what passed to C function is NULL pointer.

My Trial:

hello.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
} Foo;

int hello(Foo* what);
```

hello.c

```
#include "hello.h"

int hello(Foo* what)
{
    printf("Hello Wrapper\n");
    printf("what: %p\n", what);
    what->x = 5;
    return what->x;
}
```

phello.pxd

```
cdef extern from "hello.h":
    ctypedef struct Foo:
        int x

    cdef int hello(Foo* what)
```

phello.pyx

```
cimport phello

cdef class Foo_c:
    cdef phello.Foo* s

    def hello_fn(self):
        return phello.hello(self.s)
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
ext_modules=[ Extension("hellomodule",
                         sources=["phello.pyx", "hello.c"],
                       ) ]
```

test.py

```
import hellomodule

print "Hello test.py"

tobject = hellomodule.Foo_c()
print "Object:", tobject

tobject.hello_fn()
```

So i want create "Foo" struct in "test.py" and pass it to "hello_fn()" function to call the C function "hello()" after passing this struct, so i can read or write on this structure from both sides python & C.

Can Anyone help me in this, please?

Comment: I believe you've just got an indentation error and `hello_fn` isn't indented  so it's associated with the class `Foo_c`. With it indented correctly it compiles for me. Unfortunately it's impossible to really tell because your code formatting is a mess in the question.

Comment: @DavidW Sorry for the miss indentation, yes, it works correctly but my question was how to create structure of type "Foo" and fill it in "test.py" then pass it to "int hello(Foo* what)"  by the wrapper python function "hello_fn()".

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not allocate memory for phello.Foo. Allocation can be done in `__cinit__` with calloc (or malloc) and deallocation in `__dealloc__` with free.

```
cimport phello
from libc.stdlib cimport calloc, free

cdef class Foo_c:
    cdef phello.Foo* s

    def __cinit__(self, int n):
        self.s = <phello.Foo *>calloc(1, sizeof(phello.Foo))

    def __dealloc__(self):
        free(<void *>self.s)

    def __init__(self, int n):
        self.s.x = n
```